# Alternating printing out SharePoint List items

Tags: list

So I'm retrieving data from two different lists, (questions and answers), and want to print out the first question and then the first answer. I'm trying with for loops, but it's not working out. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
foreach (SP.ListItem listItem in jobQuestionnaires) { 
    foreach (SP.ListItem listItemTwo in answers) { 
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + listItem["QuestionText"]; 
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + listItemTwo["Answer"]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Post relevant code what you have tried so far

Comment: <code>foreach (SP.ListItem listItem in jobQuestionnaires)
{
   foreach (SP.ListItem listItemTwo in answers)
   {
      Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + listItem["QuestionText"];
Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + listItemTwo["Answer"];
 }
}</code>

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't figure out how to put this in proper indentation.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?

Comment: @Adrian Edit the original post.

Comment: The result of the for loop is that it's printing out the first question, then printing out all the answers, then printing out the second question, then all the answers, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for(int index = 0; index < jobQuestionnaires.Count; index++) {
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + jobQuestionnaires[index]["QuestionText"]; 
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + " " + answers[index]["Answer"];
}
```